# How to remove unwanted character in HTML jQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove these `","` from my HTML. I have tried `.replace(",", "")`, `.join()` and other methods but to no success.

Here is what it looks like in the console and on my page, notice the commas:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
        var featuresArray = jQuery(".Features").siblings().children("p").text().replace(",", "").split("\n");

        var boom =  featuresArray.map(function (item, index) {              
          return '<li>'+item+'</li>';
          });
        var features = boom;


        printWindow.document.write("<p class='product-attribute'>"+'Features: ' + '<ul class="product-attribute-details">' + features + "</ul></p>");
```

How can I remove these commas from my UL ?

Comment: Notice that the way you are using replace() will only replace the first instance of the search string. see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @YVH can you dump the content of `featuresArray` in the question?

Comment: If you need to remove all `,` characters,  you need to use a regular expression: `.replace(/,/g, "")`. Also, if you call `.join()`, that will add `,` between all of the strings that are being joined - you're looking for `.join("")`

Comment: @daddygames Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're concatenating the array directly with the HTML string. As such, it will have `toString()` called on it. This is effectively doing `.join(',')`. This is why the commas appear between the `li` elements, as you can see in this basic example:

```js
var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(foo.toString());
```

To fix this, manually call `join('')` on the array as you concatenate it:

```js
printWindow.document.write('<p class="product-attribute">Features: <ul class="product-attribute-details">' + features.join('') + '</ul></p>');
```

Note that I made the quotes consistent in the above line, and also removed the unnecessary concatenation you were doing in a couple of places

Comment: Thank you ! This worked well, and I learned about the toString() behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.join('')` on the array before writing it into HTML.

Since arrays aren't strings, JS will call the default `.toString()` function of the array when concatenating it with a string, which causes the extra commas to appear in the HTML:

```js
var ary = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

document.write( ary );
document.write('<br>');
document.write( ary.join( '' ) );
```